# How to prevent our URL from Cross-site scripting (XSS)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xss

Please suggest me the best way to stop Cross-site scripting (XSS) through URL.

For Example see below URL and after affect of this attack.

```
https://example.com/questions/ask.aspx?hf=15315%27%3balert("XSS")%2f%2f150
```

and after this an alert has been occur on browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate the http input request parameter, before using it as parameter or rendering in a returned page. You may be able to whitelist values for your parameter as well.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: I am new so can you please give me simple example about related question

Comment: Read through the owasp article. It has code samples and explanations

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET, you could use the `System.Web.Security.AntiXssEncoder` to wrap the text in HtmlEncode.  This should prevent malicious actors from saving scripts to your database that would execute in a browser.

```
entity.SomeValue = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(model.SomeValue);
```

Comment: For preventing XSS attack using URLs we can use `AntiXssEncoder.UrlEncode(inputFromQueryString)`